# Page refreshes itself periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I face a huge problem and I can't even start debugging, 'cause I have no clue what causes it or where to look.

I built a tourism system, which is curently runnig at http://tourx.ro/beta, and the issue is on the administration module. I'm using javascript (AJAX) to populate data to the page. The problems is that the page refreshes by itself at irregular time intervals.

It's a form page, as can be seen here :
[image: Form page]

I write some data and leave it as it is for a couple of minutes, and the page refreshes by itself. Sometimes this can happen after more than 20 minutes, sometime after only 3 minutes.

I don't have anything on my javascript that counts and/or reloads the page at any given time.

Have anyone come across something like that, or have any ideea what should I check first ? Are there some tools available so I can get a log of what's going on, to find the reason for the refresh ?

Thank you, I know this is a tricky question, but I really appreciate any hints you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried preserving the console and network requests in dev tools? Perhaps seeing the events before and after the refresh would help you identify the source of the issue.. in chrome the option would be "preserve log" on both the console and network tabs

Comment: Can you search through all included js files and inline scripts for keyword "location."

Comment: cant find admin module. well, cant understand the page, actually. darn chrome, why no translate suggestion? XD

Comment: suggestion: it may be the slick.js; it has load/unload/refresh functions in it

Comment: Slick.js it's only loaded on the "front", on "admin" it isn't. The only plugin I have in there is the csCustomScrollbar but it's not even being called on that page.
I've kept the console and I see the refresh, but I can't pinpoint any reason, just happens .... this blows my mind ..

Comment: Actually I'm begining to see a pattern, the refresh only happens if the form it's loaded by AJAX, but when the same form it's loaded directly it doesn't do it. Still can't figure out the trigger of this behaviour.

Comment: Ok guys, I've place the following command in console: "javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function() { return true }", and I've checked the Network tab to see the initiator of the reload, and it sais "<anonymous>:340" . Problem is I don't even have that many lines in the file that's requested. Any ideea ?

Comment: Are you using setInterval()  anywhere?

Comment: Are you *submitting* the form? Maybe you need an `event.preventDefault()` in there.

Comment: Yes, yes kblau, I'm using the setInterval function. Why ? Is there a faulty behavior ? No Will, I'm not submiting it. AS a mather of facts, I'm not doing anything, the page is refreshing by itself

Comment: kblau, please make an answer to this, so I can chose it as right. I do have a setInterval() on page for counting a clock, but it's supposed to run only if a specific element Id is to be found. I moved that function and the refreshes stoped. I didn't knew about this possibility, you saved me a lot of work hours, I'm deeply in your debt. Thank you.